# Should I contact arXiv if the status "on hold" is pending for a week?

Tags: mathematics, arxiv

I submitted my research article in mathematics (number theory category) on Thursday. It has been seven days since my paper status was "on hold". I have submitted several papers before, but this time it took a long time.

I always submit my articles from my supervisor's account (through cross-connection), since I don't have an arXiv account. But I have not seen so much in my previous six articles.

Why is arXiv not taking action further? Should I contact arXiv about the delay?

Comment: I am not sure, but I think that the arxiv email response always gives a reason why the paper is on hold. Which reason was could well be that action on your side is needed.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Since mid-2022, ArXiv takes longer to make papers public. The reasons were not explained. Perhaps, it has something to do with a large number of papers written in relation to Covid-19, and the fact that some preprints were used as "scientific evidence" in public/political discourse before the results were peer-reviewed and "officially" published.

At the moment, it is quite normal for a preprint to be on hold in ArXiv for 2+ weeks. Sit tight and wait patiently.

Comment: Thank you very much for the recent information. I was not aware of it.

Comment: That's interesting, but definitely not normal in my arXiv categories.

Comment: I don't think this is accurate for OP, who specified math.NT. All the preprints in that category in today's (June 2) release were submitted either on June 1 or late on May 31.

Comment: @EspeciallyLime, I submitted my preprint through "differential geometry(DG)" category mentioning the cross connection in number theory (NT). This procedure I have been following since last 3 years.

Comment: @learner I had a quick look at math.DG and papers don't seem to take noticeably longer than for math.NT.

Comment: \*[arXiv](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ArXiv)

Comment: Your information seems correct. Finally, arXiv accepted the paper on 13th day from submission. i.e., within 2 weeks

Answer (score 7):

> Let me tell you that I always submit my articles from my supervisor's account

This doesn't sound like a good idea. I can't remember the exact rules regarding submission, but why can't your supervisor endorse you to submit to your chosen arXiv category?

> Why is Arxiv not taking action further?

Who knows why.

> Should I contact Arxiv about the delay?

If you want to know why, then yes. They may also be able to advise you about how your advisor can endorse you so that you can handle the submissions properly.

Comment: Indeed, my supervisor is always a coauthor, so I submit from his account. He can not endorse me in "number theory" category because he has different "default" category. Thank you for answer.

Comment: @learner AFAIK categories one can endorse depends on whether one has published in those categories, it doesn't have to be the default category

Comment: @GoodDeeds: Presumably by "published in those categories" you mean archiving something in ArXiv in those categories? My understanding is that regardless of how much one has formally published (peer review journals), someone without an institutional address requires endorsement even for acceptance in categories one has formally published in.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro Yes, that is what I meant (archiving on arXiv in those categories), sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @GoodDeeds, to my knowledge one can endorse to a specific category if he/she has at least 4 published papers. My supervisor and I have one published article in a journal in the number-theory category, but the other 5 preprints are in arxiv. So I think my supervisor can not endorse me in the number-theory category. Of course, he can endorse me in his default category, on which I don't work.

Comment: @learner I am not sure that is how it works, according to https://info.arxiv.org/help/endorsement.html, the number of submissions needed to have been authored varies by subject but only requires that they have been submitted to arXiv, with no requirement of journal or other publications.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend that you absolutely do ***NOT*** contact arXiv about why your submission is "on hold". When I did this (e.g., cs.LG, cs.NE, cs.AI), via the suggested support channel that arXiv suggests, I found that doing so leads to a rejection of the paper. I believe the reason for this is that it is annoying to the team/support team to receive queries related to the delay/on-hold status. [Sadly, this quite readily leads to paranoia given that one never really ever knows why their work will be put on hold or is rejected -- you are receiving a peer review without access to the peer review thus you never correct for whatever reason lead to the rejection. Bear in mind that arXiv does explicitly state on their page that it will not provide reasons for rejection.]

Note that it can take 3+ weeks for work be on hold for the *cs* categories (I believe this is more likely for interdisciplinary/transdisciplinary research). Be patient and just hope for the best.

Comment: Anyway, it was accepted later

Answer (score 1):

I have generally witnessed long waiting time if I upload a word-file converted to PDF (rather than pure latex), which correlated with the fact that the work was not 100% technical but more interdisciplinary (The same observation as made by @gw109).